# Correct way to display all rows who have dates today

Tags: mysql

Is this the proper way to display all rows who have dates today.

I'm using time() to store dates in mysql, time() is a php function.

I'm getting this syntax error: 
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 DAY)))' at line 1**

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS today
FROM `myTable`
WHERE `date`
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE( NOW( ) ) )
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , 1
DAY ) ) )
```

What the problem of these?
Your help would be greatly apprciated.

Thanks!

Comment: why are you storing unix_timestamps when MySQL has such nice functions to use with its `timestamp`, `date` and `datetime` field types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `INTERVAL` is missing.  Try

```
DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Examples here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thanks mate! you made my day. Keep it up! :)